# How do I make checkbox responsive to checkout button

Tags: php, html

> I want to make a website where my user could select a tea brand and the type of tea from my checkbox and the price will display in the "Total" section below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assignment1.css">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Tea Store</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

//associative array
$tea['Red'] = "8.99";
$tea['Grey'] = "7.99";
$tea['Green'] = "11.99";



<?php
//Heading with my shop Name
echo "<h1>" . "Tea Store" . "</h1>";

?>
<!--Drop Down Menu -->

<label for="tea"></label><select name="tea" id="tea">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Select the type of tea you wish to buy</option>
    <option value="red">David's Tea</option>
    <option value="grey">Lipton</option>
    <option value="green">Twining</option>
</select>
<!--Product Categories -->
```

> Price 1 list is $8.99 , $7,99 and $11.99

> Price for 2nd brand is $9.99 , $6.99 and $12.99

> Price for 3rd brand is $4.99 , $5.99 , $9.85

> The code below is for the 1st brand

```
<form method="post">
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="teatype" value="Red" />Red Tea $8.99</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="teatype" value="Grey"/>Grey Tea $7.99</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="teatype" value="Green"/>Green Tea $11.99</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Checkout">
</form>
```

> This is where I want the price to display.

```
<?php
echo "<h2>" . "Total:" ."</h2>";
?>

<?php
echo show_source(__FILE__);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some Javascript would probably make sense here.

Comment: You should store the prices of brand 2 and brand 3 somewhere in the HTML form elements (or query the db by ajax) and then use such information to determine the "total" by JS on selection of the checkbox(es) and brand (actually in real life you should also allow the user to choose the quantity - just share my work experience) - So please consider using a shopping cart approach.